# Cannot bring any url in browser from PyCharm/selenium: http proxy responds regardless of settings

Tags: firefox, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have Python 2.7.4 and selenium bindings (installed via "pip install selenium") on Ubuntu 13.04 with Firefox 25.  I have PyCharm Community Edition 3.0.1  I'm behind a proxy.  I have a very simple python test, test_selenium.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("seleniumhq.org/")
```

When I try to run the above from PyCharm, a Firefox browser is brought up but no url shows up in the location bar.  Instead the following is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimbula/svn/nimbula/ui-selenium-tests/test-selenium.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 113, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'

The message is an html file that contains the following error:

```
The proxy could not connect to the destination in time. Please verify the site you are attempting to access and retry.\n    </td>\n  </tr>\n</table>\n<!--/Content-->\n\n<!--Info-->\n<table class="infoTable">\n  <tr>\n    <td class="infoData">\n      <b>URL: </b><script type="text/javascript">break_line("http://127.0.0.1:51991/hub/session");</script>
```

Thus from the above it looks like selenium webdriver is trying to access 127.0.0.1:5199 but the proxy intercepts the call.  I tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "<corp proxy>"
PROXY_PORT = 80

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", PROXY_PORT)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", PROXY_PORT)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", PROXY_PORT)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "127.0.0.1")
profile.update_preferences()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get("seleniumhq.org/")
```

Still the same error is displayed.  Since I have the browser window open, I checked Networking settings and they are as specified in the python code: the 127.0.0.1 shows up in the "No proxy for" box.  I also tried the following:

1. Set proxy to None in PyCharm -> Settings -> Http Proxy, execute code that does not set proxies.
2. Set proxy to "Use proxy" in PyCharm -> Settings -> Http Proxy, and specify all the required information with 127.0.0.1 in exceptions box.

None of the above worked.  I also tried executing my script from command line.  It only works if I first execute "unset http_proxy" and then execute the script without proxy settings.  If I try with proxy settings, it does not work again.  I need to be able to run the tests from PyCharm.  Thus my question is two fold:

1. How do I force no proxy from PyCharm (the Settings->Proxy->None didn't work)?  Perhaps, if I run "unset http_proxy" on command line and then start PyCharm from that same command line window, it may work.  How do I start pycharm from command line?  'pycharm' is not found, /bin/pycharm is not found either.
2. How do I force Firefox to have "None" for proxy setting from selenium?

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my findings so far:

1. Forcing PyCharm to use no proxy:

   a. In a command line window (Accessories - > Terminal) unset proxy:

   ```
   unset http_proxy
   ```

   b. Start pycharm from the same command line window:

   ```
   <install dir>/bin/pycharm.sh
   ```

   The above solves my problem.
2. I cannot find a way to set proxy in Firefox to "No proxy" from selenium/python.  When launching webdirver with the following:

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=None)
   ```

   the browser window that's launnched does not have proxy set to "No proxy" but to "Use system proxy settings".  If anyone is aware of a way to set Firefox proxy to "No proxy" programmatically from python, please share.  Otherwise, I think it is a limitation of selenium/python.

I am not certain how selenium webdriver works, but my guess is that setting browser's proxy to "No proxy" (if possible) may still not fix the above problem.  It may be necessary to have system proxy unset, in order for webdriver to work properly.  On unix use

```
unset http_proxy
```

on windows

```
set proxy to none from IE (that will change the system proxy).
```

If anybody has an explanation or better solution, please share.

Comment: It seems to me that system proxy has to be disabled, because if I set http proxy and 127.0.0.1 as an exception in the browser from python (code in the middle of this post), it works fine when system proxy is disabled, but fails otherwise with the same error.  Thus it looks like it is the internal communication of webdriver that is intercepted by the proxy and has nothing to do with browser settings.